# Young muslim boys lust problem

Tags: nikah, women, love

Asalam Aleykum, eveyone.
As a 15 years old muslim boy, I face many problems controlling my lust for women. I really want to get married and perform my fetishes on my woman in the future of course, but I want to control myself from now until I get married in thr future insh allah. Is there any dua or islamic perform to help me overcome my intensified lust for women?

Comment: It is a very common condition to every healthy boy around your age. Learn to control the urge or the urge will control you. Hold back marriage until you can afford a living for your wife and yourself. Until then, put your energy into learning and earning.

Answer (score 1):

Fast brother. Make dua to Allah to help you.

Keep yourself busy with good things.